# Python=>Pandas=> DataFrame==> While performing drop_duplicates(),

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Is there any way to keep some columns from first occurance and some columns from last occurance..?

Let's consider the following example.

```html
<pre>
    user            swiped_in           swiped_out ....
0    Bob  2019-02-25 09:50:32  2018-02-25 10:50:32 ....
1   Jane  2019-02-25 09:50:32  2019-02-25 11:50:32 ....
2  Alice  2019-02-25 09:50:32  2019-02-25 12:50:32 ....
3    Bob  2019-02-25 13:50:32  2019-02-25 14:50:32 ....
4    Bob  2019-02-25 15:50:32  2019-02-25 16:50:32 ....
</pre>
```

And it'll have some other columns which can't be predicted. But those columns should be consider for uniqueness.

Here the problem is, I want to remove the duplicates except the columns  'swipe_in' and 'swipe_out'.While removing duplicates 'swipe_in' must be first occurance and 'swipe_out' must be last occurance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with first and last aggregate function, but all another columns are lost:

```
#if need convert to datetimes and sorting
c = ['swiped_in','swiped_out']
df[c] = df[c].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df = df.sort_values(c)

df = df.groupby('user', as_index=False).agg({'swiped_in':'first', 'swiped_out':'last'})
print (df)
    user            swiped_in           swiped_out
0  Alice  2019-02-25 09:50:32  2019-02-25 12:50:32
1    Bob  2019-02-25 09:50:32  2019-02-25 16:50:32
2   Jane  2019-02-25 09:50:32  2019-02-25 11:50:32
```

If there are multiple columns with unique values need aggregate each column some aggregation function - e.g. `first`:

```
print (df)
    user            swiped_in           swiped_out col
0    Bob  2019-02-25 09:50:32  2018-02-25 10:50:32   q
1   Jane  2019-02-25 09:50:32  2019-02-25 11:50:32   w
2  Alice  2019-02-25 09:50:32  2019-02-25 12:50:32   e
3    Bob  2019-02-25 13:50:32  2019-02-25 14:50:32   r
4    Bob  2019-02-25 15:50:32  2019-02-25 16:50:32   y

c = ['swiped_in','swiped_out']
df[c] = df[c].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df = df.sort_values(c)

d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['user', 'swiped_out']), 'first')
d['swiped_out'] = 'last'

df = df.groupby('user', as_index=False).agg(d)
print (df)

    user col           swiped_in          swiped_out
0  Alice   e 2019-02-25 09:50:32 2019-02-25 12:50:32
1    Bob   q 2019-02-25 09:50:32 2019-02-25 16:50:32
2   Jane   w 2019-02-25 09:50:32 2019-02-25 11:50:32
```

Or if multiple new columns are duplicated same way like `user` column aggregate by all these columns:

```
print (df)
    user            swiped_in           swiped_out col
0    Bob  2019-02-25 09:50:32  2018-02-25 10:50:32   q
1   Jane  2019-02-25 09:50:32  2019-02-25 11:50:32   w
2  Alice  2019-02-25 09:50:32  2019-02-25 12:50:32   e
3    Bob  2019-02-25 13:50:32  2019-02-25 14:50:32   q
4    Bob  2019-02-25 15:50:32  2019-02-25 16:50:32   q

c = ['swiped_in','swiped_out']
df[c] = df[c].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df = df.sort_values(c)

cols = df.columns.difference(c).tolist()
df = df.groupby(cols, as_index=False).agg({'swiped_in':'first', 'swiped_out':'last'})
print (df)
  col   user           swiped_in          swiped_out
0   e  Alice 2019-02-25 09:50:32 2019-02-25 12:50:32
1   q    Bob 2019-02-25 09:50:32 2019-02-25 16:50:32
2   w   Jane 2019-02-25 09:50:32 2019-02-25 11:50:32
```

Comment: Hi, it works.. Thanks for ur clear explanation with solved samples.